# Laravel Update a div class from Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to use a controller to update a div class? I'm still learning Laravel here and could use some help. I have a controller with the following code:

```
    public function update()
    {
        if (Auth::check() || Auth::attempt()) {
                                $auth_id = Auth::user()->rcid;
        } else {
            $auth_id = '00000';
        }
$finalize = DB::table('AdminOperations.gen_ed_assessment.responses_data_record')
        ->where('fkey_instructor_id' , $auth_id)
        ->update(['locked' => 1]);
    return Redirect::to('/');
    }
```

When I redirect back to the default or homepage I'd like to be able to update a a menu button from `list-group-item` to `list-group-item disabled`.

My button code below:

```
<a href="section\<?php echo $data_records2;?>" class="list-group-item">Enter Your Assessments<span class="badge"><?php echo $totalrecordstofillout;?></span></a>
```

How would I parse the code in the controller to make this disabled when its redirected.

Can you use the controller to change the div class and if so how would you go about that in the controller?

Sorry if this is an elementary question for those php/laravel pros.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you can change the div class. However I can't understand based on what criteria you want it to change. Can you explain further?

Comment: I want to use the controller to update the div class, does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `session` flash, example:

```
public function update()
{
    if (Auth::check() || Auth::attempt()) {
        $auth_id = Auth::user()->rcid;
    } else {
        $auth_id = '00000';
    }

    $finalize = DB::table('AdminOperations.gen_ed_assessment.responses_data_record')
        ->where('fkey_instructor_id' , $auth_id)
        ->update(['locked' => 1]);

    if ($someCondition === true) {
        Session::flash('is_disabled', true);
    }

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

on your view:

```
 <a href="section\<?php echo $data_records2;?>" class="list-group-item<?php Session::has('is_disabled') ? ' disabled': ''; ?>">Enter Your Assessments<span class="badge"><?php echo $totalrecordstofillout;?></span></a>
```

**Edit:**
I noticed that you are using Laravel 4, so I've edited my answer.

Comment: I get an error of "call to undefined function session" when I try your snippets.

Comment: @GabrielVa I've updated my answer to make it work on Laravel 4. Use `Session::has()` instead of `session()->has()`,